# Why won't ADODB open an Access table containing a long text field in rich text format?

Tags: ms-access, adodb, richtext, longtext

This seems so dumb. I have a table with a long text (aka Memo) field, and the text format is set to Rich Text. Of course I can open the table directly or through an Access form.

What I cannot do is open the table in an ADODB recordset. Or I should say, maybe it does open (since there's no error). But it finds no rows of data.

I use a query with the ADODB recordset. I can paste the query directly into the query editor and it works. I'm using CurrentProject.Connection to connect.

Again, this doesn't generate an error. It simply retrieves no rows.

Comment: Does the same query returns rows if you use it to load a DAO recordset?  If yes, perhaps your query uses a `LIKE` pattern in its `WHERE` clause.  And then for ADO you would need to substitute `%` and `_` for the `*` and `?` wild cards in the pattern.   That was only speculation, but if it's not the problem, show us the SQL from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HansUp correctly identified the problem. The query was written using `"... Like (*SearchTerm*) ..."`

When run from the query editor window, no problem. But ADODB found no records.

On the other hand, changing the query to `"... Like (%SearchTerm%) ..."` returns no records in the query editor window, yet does return records when opened by ADODB.

Thanks!

Comment: More details about Access SQL wildcards: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5820078/77335)